# I want the view to show no results when the filter doesn't containing anything

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to use the Views module for an auto-submit field, to get the names from my taxonomies. How can I get the field to show the results after the users type something into the input box, instead of showing all the results when nothing has been entered as value for the filter?

I have tried a number of contextual filters but no luck.

This what the current search looks like, if I type in one of the terms or the field name it matches up to what I type which is how i wanted it to work, the problem is the the results are showing by default before I type anything.
[image]

Comment: do you mean an auto-complete field?

Comment: no i mean no results until the person starts typing in the letters to match the taxonomies, pretty much exactly like how this search is http://www.google.com/finance?tab=we when you type in goog it starts matching the company name

Comment: Are you looking for how to solve it using an existing module, or are you happy also with understanding how to solve this with your own module?

Comment: Either way is preferred I just want to solve it lol

Answer (score 15):

This is built into views 3:

1. Edit your view
2. Set Advanced | Exposed Form | Exposed Form Style to **input required**

Comment: Whoo hoo! this is the right answer. The other answer is fraught with difficulties and work-arounds, this one is the correct, clean way to do things IMO.

Comment: I agree, this is the correct answer.

Comment: This is THE ANSWER!!!

Answer (score 13):

If you set the exposed filter to "Required" with nothing in the default 'Value' box, then the view shows nothing until a user fills in and uses it.

Tip: If you find that your exposed filter doesn't show up when it is empty, then ([after checking 'Use AJAX' is selected if it's a block](http://drupal.org/node/1115782)) add something to the view's "No results behavior" field on the right, such as a `Global: Text area` containing a space or `&nbsp;`.

---

Another option is setting a default value that doesn't match anything - for example, if the default value is a friendly message like "Enter team name here" or "Search teams", or something neutral like "0" or "–––", there will be no matches until they enter their input, so the view will be blank until they enter input. This does mean there will be one unneccessary extra query on the page - but this should usually be cached.

If you use the default, for improved usability, you can do what the "Search finance" text in the Google page you link to does, and save your users the inconvenience of deleting that default entry themselves with some jquery code that clears the field when it gains focus, and for even better usability, you can style the default text to be lightly greyed out, then remove this style when the field gains focus.

There are lots of guides out there on how to do this, I won't duplicate them here. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289025/how-to-prepopulate-input-text-fields-with-prompting-text-which-disappears-on-typ). You could drop code like that into your theme's scripts.js file (using `Drupal.behaviors` instead of `$(document).ready` so it still works when elements get updated by AJAX). There might be a way to do this in Drupal php on the server side or in configuration too, but I don't know of one off the top of my head.

You can also get the **best of both** options, avoiding that extra query and only showing the default "Search..." text to people who have Javascript enabled (who it won't be a nuisance to), by ticking the "Required" checkbox, leaving `Value` blank, and using something like `$('#whatever-the-input-field-is').attr('value', 'Search teams');` in addition to code like the above to write in the friendly disappearing message on page load, only for people with javascript is enabled, without causing a query that will find nothing.

---

If I misunderstood your question, and it's the autocomplete feature you're asking about, then check out [autocomplete_deluxe](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe)

Comment: “If you set the exposed filter to "Required" with nothing in the default 'Value' box, then the view shows nothing until a user fills in and uses it.” — this what @JeremyLove needs I guess :)

Comment: I tried what you both suggested about the required field and the input field disappeared...

Comment: @JeremyLove See the last but one paragraph of my answer: "Tip: If you find that your exposed filter doesn't show up when it is empty, then (after checking 'Use AJAX' is selected if it's a block) add something to the view's "No results behavior" field on the right, such as a Global: Text area containing a space or `&nbsp;` "

Comment: @JeremyLove did you try adding the "No results behaviour" as suggested?

Comment: Yeah I did try that the whole view still disappeared, with your suggestions I will look into this further to see what I can figure out. Also im using view populate filters module, im wondering if that has something to do with it

Comment: Actually tried what you said before and it didnt work so I tried again and I added a label and then took it away and it worked, I dont know why... it seems a little screwy to me but thanks

Comment: Yeah I agree, I think it's probably a bug in Views that empty views which contain interactive elements that can make them non-empty aren't rendered at all by default, but realistically, I think civilisation will probably have fallen and the Internet will have become some long forgotten ancestor deity whose name is chanted around a campfire  before any patch or bug report I attempted to put into the Views queue got looked at...

Comment: Lol i'm just now seeing this. I caught a bug a while back and reported it and they got around to fixing it within a few weeks, so it is not that bad, but I will go ahead and report this to them to let them know.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit unfair, the Views guys aren't too bad, they've got a Views Bug Squad I think they call it and they've got a lot better at acting on bugs. Ctools and Panels on the other hand...